# Jquery slide from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

I have this box i want to bump or slide in from the right.

How do i do this?

My code is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.popin-window').delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);    
    });
});
```

I need the delay

Comment: can you please provide the HTML and CSS snippet of the said box as well, please? Also, include the parent as well, it would be easier to pinpoint and solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you just use, fade action, so the block just appears, if you want it to slide from the right, try this:

Into your css file, do this:

```
.popin-window {
    position: absolute;
    right: -250 /* right value */
}
```

And your javascript will be like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('.popin-window').delay(1000).animate({right: 0}, 2000);    
    });
});
```